# RecyclerView ItemAnimator glitch in Android L

Tags: android, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use the new `RecyclerView`'s `ItemAnimator` to use a different animation than `DefaultItemAnimator` for item removal. The default one works well, but when I use mine, the deleted item stays "imprinted" in the `RecyclerView`s background and the animation and other items are just drawn over it.

Here's my overriden `ItemAnimator` :

```
public static class ItemAnimator extends RecyclerView.ItemAnimator
{
  private Activity mActivity;
  private final List<ViewHolder> mPendingRemovals = new ArrayList<ViewHolder>();
  private final List<ViewHolder> mRunningRemovals = new ArrayList<ViewHolder>();

  public ItemAnimator(Activity activity)
  {
    super();
    mActivity = activity;
  }

  @Override
  public void runPendingAnimations()
  {
    for (final ViewHolder viewHolder : mPendingRemovals)
    {
      Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mActivity, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
      animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
      {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
          mRunningRemovals.remove(viewHolder);
          dispatchRemoveFinished(viewHolder);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
      });

      viewHolder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);

      mRunningRemovals.add(viewHolder);
    }

    mPendingRemovals.clear();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean animateRemove(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder)
  {
    mPendingRemovals.add((ViewHolder) viewHolder);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean animateAdd(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder)
  {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean animateMove(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i, int i2, int i3, int i4) { return false; }

  @Override
  public void endAnimation(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder)
  {
    ((ViewHolder)viewHolder).itemView.clearAnimation();
    mRunningRemovals.remove(viewHolder);
  }

  @Override
  public void endAnimations()
  {
    for (ViewHolder viewHolder : mRunningRemovals)
      viewHolder.itemView.clearAnimation();

    mRunningRemovals.clear();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isRunning()
  {
    return mRunningRemovals.size() > 0;
  }
}
```

According to the Android L documentation I believe I implemented all necessary methods and did the proper calls, so I don't see what the error could be.

Comment: I am having the same issue.  I partially fixed it by adding clearAnimation() in onAnimationEnd, but I am getting a crash when two or more animations happen at once.  `        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
          viewHolder.itemView.clearAnimation();
          mRunningRemovals.remove(viewHolder);
          dispatchRemoveFinished(viewHolder);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, with RecyclerView, you have to use ViewCompat.animate() from the support library to animate views with rather than the Animation class.  I was having the same issues, and when I switched to using ViewCompat, all the glitches went away.  Also, this is how it is done in the Android source code for DefaultItemAnimator.

Comment: Sorry about my previous comment saying your comment was another issue, I thought I was on another question about animations at the time. Thanks for your input, I cannot test it for now but I will asap and keep you informed.

Comment: No problem, it wasn't clear whether it was related or not.  Hope this fixes it for you.